# What is the max number of users per room on ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd, multiuserchat

We are using ejabberd_16.01-0_amd64.deb and we want to set max number of users per room to 10000. According to doc: (https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#modmuc)

> max_users: Number: This option defines at the service level, the
>   maximum number of users allowed per room. It can be lowered in each
>   room configuration but cannot be increased in individual room
>   configuration. The default value is 200.

On the other hand,

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/src/mod_muc_room.erl#L58

says, it could be also 5000.

We have tried 10000, but it didn't work (of course, values lower then 200 did work ).

Can anyone please advice us, what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we tried to set max users per room to 5000 and that worked.

> max_users: Number: This option defines at the service level, the
>   maximum number of users allowed per room. It can be lowered in each
>   room configuration but cannot be increased in individual room
>   configuration. The default value is 200.

It looks like, I misunderstood what the doc says: The limit max users per room is set globally. It can be only lowered per room (it can't be increased over the global maximum).

Note: we would expect the server to log an error or at least a warning, why value 10000 can't be set, but we couldn't find anything.